# Virtual POS printer

Tags: vb.net, printing, virtual, simulator, point-of-sale

Is there any Virtual POS printer software (Simulator) available in Internet. Please share details. Currently I don't have any physical POS printer. But I need to check whether my output is correct or not. Its better it will be a vb.net.

Comment: Hvae you even tried to use a search engine? There is POS for .NET lib from Microsoft...

Comment: yes I did. but couldn't find any

Answer (score 1):

From the ***POS for .NET*** FAQ: [Which device simulators does POS for .NET include?](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee406171(v=winembedded.4).aspx#Q3)

**MSDN:**

> Which device simulators does POS for .NET include? When you install
>   the POS for .NET Software Development Kit (SDK), it includes several
>   device simulators. The simulators provide a simple means of simulating
>   a device when no physical device is available. The simulators are
>   helpful during the early stages of development, during prototyping,
>   and for testing configurations before deployment. POS for .NET
>   includes simulators for the following device categories:
>
> - Bar Code Scanner
> - Cash Drawer
> - Check Scanner
> - Keylock
> - Line Display
> - Magnetic Stripe Reader (MSR)
> - PIN Pad
> - POS Keyboard
> - POS Printer

Comment: the problem is that the POS Printer simulator included can't "print" graphics. It's text mode only.